# Kotlin compiler returning: Unresolved reference: springframework in Spring 5.0

Tags: spring, maven, kotlin

I'm trying to start playing around with using Kotlin together with Spring 5.0 however I am having issues with the Kotlin compiler not recognising any reference to Spring:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.1.1:compile (compile) on
> project kotlin-mvc-project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
>
> [ERROR] (file location):[7,12] Unresolved reference: springframework

I'm using the spring milestone version Spring 5.0.0.M5 and Kotlin version 1.1.1 (on both my kotlin-compiler and IntelliJ Kotlin plugin). There are no compile errors highlighted by the IDE in any of my Kotlin files but running the kotlin-compiler it seems to not see Spring 5.0 at all.

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? I'm using Maven for this project, I've attached my POM for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>kotlin-mvc-project</groupId>
<artifactId>kotlin-mvc-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.1.1</kotlin.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.0.M5</spring.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>spring-milestones</id>
    <name>Spring Milestones</name>
    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

Comment: Could you please post the part of the file where the error is occuring?

Comment: Sorry not sure what file you mean? I get these errors when the kotlin-compiler runs after calling mvn clean install

Comment: I've managed to fix this for now by rolling back to the current release version of Spring. 4.3.7.RELEASE. No idea why I can't get 5.0 to work though

Comment: `[ERROR] (file location):[7,12] Unresolved reference: springframework` This error I meant -- what's on the line where this occurs?

Comment: Ah right. It was just

        import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

There is one of those errors for every reference to a spring object in the code.

Comment: @Plog I tried your configuration and it works for me. Could you provide some more details: maven version, project structure? May I take a look at your project?

Comment: I moved on to use an older version of Spring but the project can be found here: https://github.com/TLDC/KotlinMVCSeleniumShowcase. Just changing the Spring version in the pom for the kotlin-mvc module back to 5.0.0.M5 gives me the same issue though.

Comment: @Plog I've checked out your master, changed spring version in the kotlin-mvc project and it built and even started

Comment: That is... very odd. Something funny must be going on in my local Maven repo

Comment: @Plog What Maven version are you using? Could you please try to drop you local maven repo? And could you answer with `@` symbol mentioning my name?:)

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich sorry I didnt know about the @ oops! I really appreciate your help. You helped me realise it was nothing wrong with my pom. I added an answer after investigating. Wont let me award the bounty but I will pay you back in other ways!

Comment: @Plog That's very nice of you :) glad I was helpful, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After help from @DmitrySenkovich in narrowing down that it was not an issue with my pom I investigated what could be going wrong in my local maven repository. I checked out the jars in my .m2 folder and they seemed a bit wrong and missing certain things. I tried wiping the maven repo but they kept being pulled back the same.

This issue was on a corporate machine and after doing some investigation it seems our maven settings.xml were configured to pull down dependencies from a company wide Artifactory and not maven central/any other repo.

Dependencies are supposed to be pulled down into this Arifactory from other repositories as required but for whatever reason (I assume because they were being pulled down from a repo other than maven central) the jars for the milestone Spring builds were not pulling down correctly. By removing these and manually adding the jars to Artifactory I was able to finally resolve the issue.